# Which objects are available for GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am writing the program, which should be optimized for usage of heap and GC. Based on this I need to create as less objects as possible. So I am wondering if it is a matter for GC if I write the commands in one line?

For example this code creates 2 objects, which are avaliable for GC:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
String s = uuid.toString();
```

What if I rewrite this code in one line, like this:

```
String s = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Will the second variant also create 2 objects for GC or only the String object?

Comment: Both lines are identical in regard to the objects that will be created. But you can be assured that it won't be only two objects. Without checking the current implementations of `UUID.randomUUID()` and `UUID.toString()`, I would bet on at least six temporary objects plus the final `String`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference whatsoever between those two lines as far as the GC (or, really, any part of Java) is concerned.

It's very unusual to need to worry about optimizing for heap.  Do you have a program that already works and takes too much heap, or does too much GC?  If not, *do not worry about it*.  This is premature optimization which will likely make things worse.  Java's GC is really, really good at what it does.    If you are not sure about the difference between those two lines, then you should trust Java to be take care of its own memory usage.

Comment: thank you for your answer, in my case time which is used by GC is very important, because the program works on the real-time data, and the delay in 1ms (for GC) is critical.

Comment: The appropriate way to deal with that is to write your program and then  tune the garbage collector settings, not to try to redesign your program -- especially not if you don't know that those two versions of your code have no difference between them.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, tuning of GC we also use

Comment: @Balconsky if you worry about performance, you should rethink your need for a generated UUID.